# Receiving an error when attempting to open a url link with urlopen

Tags: python, python-2.7, urllib2, urlopen

I am attempting to run this portion of my code that used to work before, but now I get the following error, `urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error [SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION] tlsv1 alert protocol version (_ssl.c:661)`. It never used to do that, and everything worked fine. The line that fails is the `urlopen`. Does anyone have any suggestions? I am using Python 2.7 and I am aware it is very outdated.

```
image_url = 'https://openweathermap.org/img/wn/'+icon+'@2x.png'
image_str = urlopen(image_url).read()
```

Was expecting it to open the weather icon like it used to.

Comment: Just as a reminder: Python 2.7 is not maintained, even to apply security fixes, and has been in that state for over three years. It is comparable to Windows 7 in terms of how outdated it is.